# Cannot use (!=) to check char values

Tags: while-loop, char

Im trying to make a while loop that checks to see if a user inputted character is correct. If the character is incorrect, the loop is supposed to run until it is. However, when i enter this loop I cannot exit, even if i input the correct value. Any help would be appreciated!

```
if (userInputCheck == 'U' || userInputCheck == 'D' || userInputCheck == 'R' || userInputCheck == 'L'){

        return userInputCheck;
    }

    else

    while(userInputCheck != 'U' || userInputCheck != 'D' || userInputCheck != 'R' || userInputCheck != 'L'){

        System.out.println("ERROR. Please enter U for up, D for down, R for right, or L for left");
        String temp = keyboard.next();
        userInputCheck = temp.charAt(0);
    }

    return userInputCheck;
```

Comment: You should add a specific language tag in order to draw the attention of those familiar with the language you're using, who will be better able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

A test like `x != 'U' || x != 'D'` will *ALWAYS* be true -- think about it.  If the chracter entered is `U` the first test will be false, but the second will be true, so the whole thing will be true.  You want use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
while(userInputCheck != 'U' && userInputCheck != 'D' && ...
```

Once you do this, there's also no need for the first `if`...